# Как лучше реализовать клиент-сервер на python?

Tags: python, сокет, клиент-сервер, long-poll

У меня есть телеграм бот. Я хочу через него выполнять примерно следующий список действий:

- боту приходит команда
- в зависимости от команды, он должен выбрать один из ~15 компьютеров, которые стоят за NAT-ом и отослать эту команду им через интернет.
- скрипт, находящийся на удаленном компьютере вносит запись в БД, а затем мониторит некоторое время эту БД на появление новых записей и отсылает их обратно боту.

Никак не могу придумать, как реализовать такой клиент-сервер. Использовать сокеты? Лонг-поллинг? Просто поллинг?

Comment: https://github.com/fatedier/frp

эта штука позволяет не беспокоиться за NAT;
очень удобно, но не для hiload / life-critical;

может новые идеи у вас будут

Comment: STUN и подобное пробовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил реализовать при помощи flask-socketio на стороне сервера и socketio-client на стороне клиента.